# Creating a list of all possible lists, given each element can take one of n values

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell I'm trying to create a function with the typing `Int -> [a] -> [[a]]`, that generates a list such as: `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]` where each element in the smaller lists can take the value of either 1 or 0. Each of the smaller lists has the same size, which in this case is 2. If the size of the smaller lists was 3, I would expect to get the output `[[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]`

I've looked in to the `permutations` function, but this does not achieve exactly what I want. I believe there is also a `variate` function, but I cannot access this library.

Rather than the exact function (which would also be useful), what would be the process to generate such a list?

Comment: One straightforward approach would be to use direct recursion on the first (`Int`) parameter - with cases for `0` and for `n` in terms of `n - 1`.

Comment: The `Int` parameter here is the size of each of the smaller lists. Looking at the second example, how would you create 8 smaller lists with only 3 recursions (If each recursion called the function with `n - 1`)?

Comment: Well, when the second parameter is `[0, 1]` as here, you can get from the `n - 1` case to the `n` case by prepending `0` to all the elements, and then prepending `1` to all the elements. I'm sure you can generalise this.

Comment: [`replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) does exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As oisdk mentions in a comment, a more general version of this exact function is already defined, with the name `Control.Monad.replicateM`:

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad (replicateM)
Prelude Control.Monad> replicateM 3 [0,1]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the list monad for this:

```
example :: [[Int]]
example = do
    x <- [0,1]
    y <- [0,1]
    pure [x,y]

ghci> example
[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

Play with this.  Then you should be able to combine it with recursion on `n` to create the function you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the specification, but from the examples, one possible definition is

```hs
lists :: Int -> [[Int]]
lists 0 = [[]]
lists n = map (0:) xss ++ map (1:) xss
  where xss = lists (n-1) 

-- λ> lists 2
-- [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
-- λ> lists 3
-- [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another definition, using comprehension instead of map, is

```hs
lists :: Int -> [[Int]]
lists 0 = [[]]
lists n = [x:xs | x <- [0,1], xs <- lists (n-1)] 

-- λ> lists 2
-- [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
-- λ> lists 3
-- [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Comment: yes; `[... | x <- a++b, ...]` == `[... | x <- a, ...] ++ [... | x <- b, ...]` is a nice identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *sequence* function.
Like this:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :t sequence
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
 λ> 
 λ> let { allLists :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]] ; allLists n xs = sequence $ replicate n xs ; }
 λ> 
 λ> allLists 3 [0,1]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
 λ>
```